# How do I only keep the string numbers in a String array in Java?

Tags: java

I have an array that looks like this in Java:

```
["55", "5280", "the", "name", "here", "200"]
```

How do I return:

```
[55, 5280, 200]
```

Comment: Why is `"200"` to be kept as string, but `55` and `5280` are converted to integers?

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Comment: this is equivalent to solving the question "How do I know that a string represent a number?" If you can answer that, then you've got your answer

Comment: What's the pattern? Why is 200 a `String`?

Comment: the question is unclear, please explain what do you really want to accomplish

Comment: Loop through the elements of the array and invoke Integer.parseInt() on all elements. Keep the ones that return int and ignore the ones that does not or throw exceptions .

Comment: `int[] arr = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"55", "5280", "the", "name", "here", "200"}).filter(s->s.matches("\\d+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: @Gopi but strings get parsed into 0...

Comment: What do you mean by " but strings get parsed into 0"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @jwan622 strings that can't be converted to numbers throw NumberFormat exception.

Comment: One step at a time ... **1)** How to parse a `String` in a number. **2)** How to catch exception if parsing a non-number. **3)** How to repeat for the array...

Comment: Are the numbers allowed to have signs (`+200`, `-45`)? Any magnitude ( `461923873245234234184322342`)? Thousand separators? Decimal fractions?

Answer (score 4):

Filter only number strings using regex, then convert strings to int.

```
int[] result = Stream.of(stringArray)
        .filter(Pattern.compile("^[\\d]+$").asPredicate())
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
    Arrays.stream(array)
            .flatMapToInt(this::convertSafely)
            .toArray();
```

and this is the helper method:

```
    private IntStream convertSafely(String s) {
        try {
            return IntStream.of(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return IntStream.empty();
        }
    }
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, using exceptions as flow control has several cons, which you should consider against the alternative of using regex (I have a slight paranoia of them).

If your code needs high-performance, go for regex. I think this solution is more readable.

---

**Edit**:

I recently saw [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number) baeldung blog which adds more options and compares performance - at least by first findings exception has better performance, but there is a suggested improvement to the regex option.

Comment: I could argue that hiding an exception is "safe".

Comment: The point is not to throw it in the middle of a stream. And it functions as specified, meaning non-convertable strings will be ignored.

Comment: I agree with AxelH and also returning `null` is bad when we can just return `Optional` at least.

Comment: How about this?

Comment: I like it. For many purposes you would probably want to return an `IntStream` from `convertSafely` and collect into an `int` array (the syntax used in the question, without quotes, may also suggest an `int` array).

Comment: This seems to be using exceptions for control flow, which is an anti-pattern. Finding a non-integer string is expected, and not exceptional.

Comment: I see your point, @KlitosKyriacou. To me the greater good is leaving it to a proven library method to determine whether a string has the syntax of an integer, so I prefer to live with the bad smell of using an exception. And blaming the design of the `Integer` class, which doesn’t have a method for this purpose that doesn’t throw `NumberFormatException`. Which, BTW, should be the exception type to catch in the code, not a general `Exception`.

Comment: On performance: Regular expressions tend to be expensive performancewise, so I wouldn’t be convinced that they perform any better than throwing and catching an exception. If it matters, one will have to do some measurements on both approaches. Or simply write one’s own number parser, which could surely outperform both.